# Ошибка в коде программы

Tags: c++, массивы, visual-c++, динамические-массивы

Столкнулся с проблемой в коде:

> 1)**error C2057**: требуется константное выражение
>
> 2)**error C2466**:
>   невозможно выделить память для массива постоянного нулевого размера
>   3)**error C2133**: List: неизвестный размер

Сам код программы:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "locale"
using namespace std;
struct CPU
{
   string Name;
   float Hz;
   int RAM;
   int SRAM;
   int Price;};

int main()
{
   int count;

   cin>>count;
   CPU List[count];
   for (int i=0;i<count;i++) {
     cout<<"Name ";cin>>List[i].Name;
     cout<<"HZ ";cin>>List[i].Hz;
     cout<<"RAM ";cin>>List[i].RAM;
     cout<<"SRAM ";cin>>List[i].SRAM;
     cout<<"Price ";cin>>List[i].Price;
   }
   system("pause");
}
```

В чем причина?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя в C++ объявлять массивы с размером, неизвестным во время компиляции.

Меняйте

```
CPU List[count];
```

на

```
CPU * List = new CPU[count];
```

и в конце не забудьте добавить

```
delete[] List;
```